# Function that works on both Num and List

Tags: haskell

I am doing this as an pattern matching exercise.

I would like to have a function that will work on both `Num` type and `List` type. For example:

```
double 20
double [1,2,3,4,5]
```

The code works till

```
double [] = []
double (x : xs) = (2 * x) : (double xs)

main = do
    let x = [1,2,3,4,5]
    print (double x)
```

But when I try:

```
double x = x + x
double [] = []
double (x : xs) = (2 * x) : (double xs)

main = do
    let x = [1,2,3,4,5]
    print (double 20)
    print (double x)
```

It gives error.

What should be done here?

Comment: In Haskell, a function must have a type. In most common cases, the type must choose whether the domain of the function is, say, `Int` or `[Int]`. It can not be both. In principle, one could use more advanced constructs like type classes to accept both integers and lists, but I am not sure it would be a good idea. What's wrong with using two separate functions? `double = (*2)` and `doubleList = map double`.

Comment: @chi I just wanted to know whether this is possible or not (learning, newbie). Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: `deriving via Ap ZipList a instance Num a => Num [a]` is the only way to support it without a type annotation on the numeric literal, but the wrong thing here is wanting one function that works on both lists and numbers in the first place. You should write two separate functions and use them separately rather than mixing intentions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned by chi, it's better to have separate functions. I would add that, especially whilst you're learning, it's a [good habit](https://wiki.haskell.org/Type_signatures_as_good_style) to think about and write the type signatures of your functions.

For the sake of answering your question, you can still do this.

You tell Haskell that the `Integer` and `[Integer]` data types "can be doubled", and then define how you do that for each type. I understand that this is more advanced than what you're asking however :)

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

class CanDouble a where
    double :: a -> a

instance CanDouble Integer where
    double = (*2)

instance CanDouble [Integer] where
    double = map (*2)
```

```hs
> double 5
10
> double [1,2,3]
[2,4,6]
```

Comment: It gives error "Illegal instance declaration for ‘CanDouble [Integer]’"

Comment: Turn on [`FlexibleInstances`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/instances.html#extension-FlexibleInstances). The GHC error should already have it as a suggestion. @AhmadIsmail

Comment: easier to do a general instance: `instance CanDouble a => CanDouble [a] where double = map double`

Comment: @RobinZigmond can you give the full code?

Comment: @AhmadIsmail: that is the full code.

Comment: Indeed it is, but note that I put it on one line to fit it in a comment - in practice I'd start a new line, with indentation, after the `where`.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [using typeclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74279175/15261315) as in Haren's answer, you can use `Either Int [Int]`.

```
double :: Either Int [Int] -> Either Int [Int]
double (Left n) = Left $ n * 2
double (Right lst) = Right $ map (* 2) lst
```

```
ghci> double (Left 5)
Left 10
ghci> double (Right [1,2,3])
Right [2,4,6]
```